# SNAT target option in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, ip, failover

I have a remote server where I have added a new `FAILOVER IP` in a new interface, `ETH0:0`. Everything works perfectly; IP is setup.  I want the traffic that is coming from `ETH0:0` to use the `ETH0:0` as the IP source. For example, when I send emails from my SERVER it uses The `ETH0` IP which is not what I want.

So, the traffic coming from `ETH0` use its IP in Source IP of The Packet, 
and the traffic coming from `ETH0:0` uses its IP and so on. Here is what I have tried:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0:0 -j SNAT --to-source 51.XXX.XXX.XXX ;`

Where the interface `ETH0:0`  Has the IP `51.XXX.XXX.XXX`.

Thank you!

Comment: Try with `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 51.XXX.XXX.XXX`, just removing the **:0** from the outbound interface.

Comment: it Made all the outgoing traffic having the same source IP which is  51.XXX.XXX.XXX , no matter what is the interface the traffic is comming from .

Answer (score 0):

IP tables does not differentiate eth0:0 from eth0. In fact, eth0:0 will not work because eth0:x is an alias to the interface eth0 not a different one. Try something like this.

```
echo 200 ip2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from eth0:0 dev eth0:0 table ip2
ip route add default via <gateway_IP> dev eth1 table ip2
```

This will route your traffic from the same incoming interface but might not work for aliases